# Automating Permission Sets for packaging with dependencies?

Tags: apex, managed-package, permission-sets

I am looking to create permission sets for my managed packages. I am finding it very time-consuming and error-prone for me to manually make sure that the permission set I am creating has all the required dependencies to make the package work for the user installing it.

My vivid vision is to create a managed package and then be able to automate the creation of a permission set that is based on the objects, fields, apex classes, etc. in the managed package.

When creating a permission set for a managed package, what is the best practice to make sure that the permission set has all the CRUD access rights necessary to make sure the package is installed correctly?

Then, as the package expands or contracts, how can I make sure that this permission set is being updated appropriately?

Comment: I think the simplest option is to pull information from Admin profile and copy-paste it into Permission Set

Comment: @ytiq This seems like a security issue.

Comment: You can write code to generate permission sets so you can use a higher level notion to generate the lower level permission set XML files. In one case I used `sed` scripts to generate variations of a base permission set XML file to improve consistency. But the bottom line is that permission sets are very detailed so it is easy for then to become inconsistent and it is hard to test to be sure everything is good.